# Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 not getting 5.0.2 update

Tags: updates, samsung, samsung-galaxy-tab-4

I am working on provisioning several (3) Samsung Galaxy Tab 4's Model SM-T530, and one of them is not getting the latest system updates.  It is stuck at Android 4.4.2, Kernel version 3.4.0-3235464.  I have tried manually running the Update now, verified I am online, all that fun stuff.

This is the WiFi Only version, so it is not dependent on the carrier releasing the update, and the other two that were purchased from the same vendor at the same time, updated just like they were supposed to, and are now at 5.0.2.

What can i do to troubleshoot this issue?  (Logs, check settings, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update will took some time to become available in every country.

If you check on [Sammobile](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/SM-T530/), 5.0.2 was released today (2015-07-16), and it is for United Kingdom. There no version for other countries.

You can flash UK version via Odin, but better wait some days for it to get released for other countries. After that you should be able to update it via OTA, without risks of bricking, flashing...

---

As it is WiFi only version, your tab doesn't depends on Country Code and it can work with any, it is just recommended to have version that is at least near you (like not installing Korean version, if you're from USA/EU (because of language, stock apps, QoL changes, compatibilty problems, etc)).

**I just want to notice, as I already said this process is NOT recommended.**

This involves flashing new ROM using Odin. This process can be risky, it can cause soft (even hard) brick. You should still have warranty, because package is signed by Samsung and it does not trigger binary counter but you never know.

It is best to wait even 1-2 weeks so it gets deployed in every region, but I think it will available in some days so it is not worth trying it...

**Keep in mind if you want to continue, do backup! If something bad happens, you will have to do factory data reset, so you can be on safe side, if you need to format it**

---

Process of installing new ROM:

1. Download new ROM for your device variant from Sammobile.
2. When you download, you will ususally get ZIP, that contains one `.tar.md5` and one `.dll`. Ignore `.dll` and unpack only `.tar.md5`.
3. Download Samsung USB driver and install it.
4. Download Odin and unpack it.
5. Make sure you disable A/V before you start flashing, it can cause fail. Also you must kill all Samsung Kies processes before flashing or flash will fail.
6. Go to Settings -> About Phone -> Tap some times (as I recall it is 6-8 taps) on build number. It will enable developer options.
7. Go Back and find Developer options. Enable it if it isn't. Also you must enable USB debugging and authorize your PC (don't forget to remember choice!).
8. Reboot your device to Download mode (find on Google, how to do it for your tab), and plugin USB.
9. Open Odin. Now you will see some 'blue' colored box where it says COM something. It means that your device is connected.
10. **Be sure that you ONLY HAVE CHECKED F. Reset Time and Auto-Reboot! Repartition MUST STAY UNCHECKED !**
11. Click on PDA and select `.tar.md5`, you previously unpacked. Let it some time to check everything.
12. Start the process. **DO NOT UNPLUG USB OR IT WILL BRICK DEVICE.** If everything went well, your device will reboot into Android Lollipop 5.1 ready to use.

---

Also, Keep in mind - I or this site will not be held responsible if your device get brick after following this process. You should be on safe side but when you flashing and using Odin, you never know what can happen. In 99.9% of time it worked very well for me, but you never know. Good luck

Comment: The United States isn't even an option on that list.  I have other tab 4's that have received the updates without issue.

Comment: It can depend on country code of tablet. You can always install this app and check that information on tabs - [Phone INFO Samsung](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.vndnguyen.phoneinfo). As I said, you can flash it with Odin, but it is not recommended for compatibility and etc. It is better to wait 2-3 days, if not I can update post with futher instructions

Comment: That explains it!  the two that updated are France, released on June 15th, the one that didn't has a Germany code, which has not yet been released.  Any idea if it is possible to manually download and install that?  the Sammobile site has the link, but it still has the France country code on it.

Comment: I added solution for reflashing ROM, you can read it and deceide do you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Download the Samsung USB Drivers and install them on your PC.

With the drivers installed, you will be able to successfully connect your tablet to your PC. ODIN is the application that you will have to use in order to flash the updates files on your Galaxy Tab 4.

**Make sure that you don’t have any antivirus app running nor the Samsung KIES program. Enable USB Debugging from Developer Options menu.**

If you are installing the Android 5.0.2 XXU1BOD8 firmware over a custom ROM, 
then you should know that you will be forced to apply an extra ‘factory reset’ step.

For more details you can visit Samsung India site.