# I dont know if my tablet is broken or outdated

Tags: google-play-store, system

Well, I have a Samsung galaxy tab 4 (4.4.2) and I rooted it. So I reset it because Google play didn't work.but after factory reset it still didn't work. I uninstalled updates cleared cache, and I tried to system update today, and that didnt work. So I'm trying to find a way to get my system updates working, and Google play working.
**HELP**

Comment: re-flash stock rom again, it will unroot completely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 not getting 5.0.2 update](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/115325/samsung-galaxy-tab-4-not-getting-5-0-2-update)

Answer (score 0):

OTA system updates won't work if you've modified the system image in any way, including by rooting. To get back to a working state, you need to flash the "stock" ROM, i.e. an unmodified official ROM from Samsung. See [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device) for details of how to find a stock ROM, and then [this existing answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/115461/12442) describes in detail how to use Odin to install a ROM on the Galaxy Tab 4.